# Sum Series with Functions - Continously adding previous answers?

Tags: python, function, math, sum, continuous

I'm learning the concepts of functions in Python and could use a little advice.

I'm trying to write a program that will use the algebraic function `m(i) = (i) / (i + 1)` for inputs 1 through 20. So far I've got that to work, but now I want to add all previous outputs together for each new output. It could be I'm just not grasping the mathematical concept of this and that's why I'm not getting it right in my code.

Ideally this would be the result table I'm trying to get:

```
i      m(i)     

1      0.50
2      1.17
...
19    16.40
20    17.35
```

Currently what I have is:

```
def equation(i):
    mi = ((i) / (i + 1))
    return mi

def main():
    for i in range(1,21):
    print(format(i, '2d'),"    ",format(equation(i), '.2f'))

main()
```

The output I'm seeing in my shell is:

```
 1      0.50
 2      0.67
 3      0.75
 4      0.80
 5      0.83
 6      0.86
 7      0.88
 8      0.89
 9      0.90
10      0.91
11      0.92
12      0.92
13      0.93
14      0.93
15      0.94
16      0.94
17      0.94
18      0.95
19      0.95
20      0.95
```

I feel like I'm off to a good start, but how can I add all the m(i) together for each new line? Like in the 'ideal' example I posted, it takes 0.5 + 0.67 giving 1.17 and so on.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def equation(i):
    if i <= 0:
        return 0
    mi = ((i) / (i + 1))
    return mi + equation(i - 1)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thank you Hydex! Now I just need to study that piece of code and try to understand why it works

Comment: If you need more information about recursive functions see this link [python-course](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) and [Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You just need an accumulator to save the values of equation(i)

Here's my solution:

```
def equation(i):
    mi = ((i) / (i + 1))
    return mi

acc = 0
for i in range(1,21):
    acc += equation(i)
    print(format(i, '2d'),"    ",format(acc, '.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def equation(i):
    mi = (float(i) / (i + 1))
    return mi

def main():
    sumOfMi = 0
    for i in range(1,21):
        sumOfMi+= equation(i)
        print(format(i, '2d'),"    ",format(sumOfMi, '.2f'))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a generator:

```
def equation(i):
    n = 0
    tot = 0
    while n < i: 
         n += 1
         mi = n/(n+n)
         tot += mi
         yield n, tot

def main():
    for i, mi in equation(21):
        print(format(i, '2d'),"    ",format(mi, '.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(i):
    return i/(i+1)

e = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
    print(i, end=' ')
    e += function(i)
    print(e)
```

Seems you just need to increment resulting return from function to variable.Good luck!